# Jest not auto mocking common js modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to wrap my head around testing Flux and React applications using Jest.

I started using [Scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-simple-shopping-cart-with-react-js-and-flux) as my starting point and will be creating a full test suite to gain knowledge in how to structure my first real react and flux app.

You can [find my code on github](https://github.com/resonantbreath/react-flux-shopping-cart/tree/master/hello) to see where I am at.

The test that does not run is [FluxProduct-test.jsx](https://github.com/resonantbreath/react-flux-shopping-cart/blob/master/hello/app/assets/javascripts/components/__tests__/FluxProduct-test.jsx)

```js
jest.dontMock('../FluxProduct');

var React
  , TestUtils
  , FluxProduct
  , FluxCartActions;

describe('FluxProduct', function() {


  var SAMPLE = {
    product: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Name',
      image: 'image.png',
      description: 'this description',
      variants: [
        {
          sku: '123',
          type: 'First',
          price: 1.99,
          inventory: 1
        },
        {
          sku: '456',
          type: 'Second',
          price: 2.99,
          inventory: 3
        },
        {
          sku: '789',
          type: 'Third',
          price: 3.99,
          inventory: 2
        }
      ]
    },
  };


  function getElement(product, className)
  {
    return product.getDOMNode().getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
  }

  function getElementByTag(product, tagName)
  {
    return product.getDOMNode().getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0];
  }

  function selectIsActive(select, text)
  {
    for( var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
    {
      if (select.options[i].textContent == text)
      {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  beforeEach(function(){
    React = require('react/addons')
    , TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils
    , FluxProduct = require('../FluxProduct')
    , FluxCartActions = require('../../actions/FluxCartActions');
  });

  it('should have the display all of the fields', function() {
    var cartItems = [];
    var selected = SAMPLE.product.variants[1];
    var product = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <FluxProduct selected={selected} product={SAMPLE.product} cartitems={cartItems} />
    );

    expect(getElement(product, 'name').textContent).toEqual(SAMPLE.product.name);
    expect(getElement(product, 'description').textContent).toEqual(SAMPLE.product.description);
    expect(getElement(product, 'price').textContent).toEqual('Price: $' + selected.price);
    expect(selectIsActive(getElementByTag(product, 'select'), selected.type)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should allow to add another variant', function() {
    var cartItems = [];
    var selected = SAMPLE.product.variants[1];
    var targetVariantIndex = 2;
    var targetVariant = SAMPLE.product.variants[targetVariantIndex];
    var product = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <FluxProduct selected={selected} product={SAMPLE.product} cartitems={cartItems} />
    );
    var selectElement = getElementByTag(product, 'select');
    var addToCartBtn = getElementByTag(product, 'select');

    TestUtils.Simulate.change(selectElement, { target: { value: targetVariantIndex } });

    expect(selectIsActive(selectElement, targetVariant.type)).toEqual(true);

    TestUtils.Simulate.click(addToCartBtn);

    expect(FluxCartActions.addToCart.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(FluxCartActions.addToCart.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(targetVariant.sku);
    expect(FluxCartActions.addToCart.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe({
      name: targetVariant.name,
      type: targetVariant.type,
      price: targetVariant.price
    });
  });
});
```

It comes back with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined" on line 100.

When I log out FluxActions it seems that it is not being automocked, which is the reason mock is undefined and accessing the calls property is throwing the error.

fyi: Jest requires Node 0.10, does not run on 0.12

Helpful reference files:

[FluxProduct.jsx](https://github.com/resonantbreath/react-flux-shopping-cart/blob/master/hello/app/assets/javascripts/components/FluxProduct.js)

```js
var React = require('react');
var FluxCartActions = require('../actions/FluxCartActions');

// Flux product view
var FluxProduct = React.createClass({

  // Add item to cart via Actions
  addToCart: function(event){
    var sku = this.props.selected.sku;
    var update = {
      name: this.props.product.name,
      type: this.props.selected.type,
      price: this.props.selected.price
    }
    FluxCartActions.addToCart(sku, update);
    FluxCartActions.updateCartVisible(true);
  },

  // Select product variation via Actions
  selectVariant: function(event){
    FluxCartActions.selectProduct(event.target.value);
  },

  // Render product View
  render: function() {
    var ats = (this.props.selected.sku in this.props.cartitems) ?
      this.props.selected.inventory - this.props.cartitems[this.props.selected.sku].quantity :
      this.props.selected.inventory;
    return (
      <div className="flux-product">
        <img src={'assets/' + this.props.product.image}/>
        <div className="flux-product-detail">
          <h1 className="name">{this.props.product.name}</h1>
          <p className="description">{this.props.product.description}</p>
          <p className="price">Price: ${this.props.selected.price}</p>
          <select onChange={this.selectVariant}>
            {this.props.product.variants.map(function(variant, index){
              return (
                <option key={index} value={index}>{variant.type}</option>
              )
            })}
          </select>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addToCart} disabled={ats  > 0 ? '' : 'disabled'}>
            {ats > 0 ? 'Add To Cart' : 'Sold Out'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

});

module.exports = FluxProduct;
```

[FluxCartActions.js](https://github.com/resonantbreath/react-flux-shopping-cart/blob/master/hello/app/assets/javascripts/actions/FluxCartActions.js)

```js
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var FluxCartConstants = require('../constants/FluxCartConstants');

// Define action methods
var FluxCartActions = {

  // Receive inital product data
  receiveProduct: function(data) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: FluxCartConstants.RECEIVE_DATA,
      data: data
    })
  },

  // Set currently selected product variation
  selectProduct: function(index) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: FluxCartConstants.SELECT_PRODUCT,
      data: index
    })
  },

  // Add item to cart
  addToCart: function(sku, update) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: FluxCartConstants.CART_ADD,
      sku: sku,
      update: update
    })
  },

  // Remove item from cart
  removeFromCart: function(sku) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: FluxCartConstants.CART_REMOVE,
      sku: sku
    })
  },

  // Update cart visibility status
  updateCartVisible: function(cartVisible) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: FluxCartConstants.CART_VISIBLE,
      cartVisible: cartVisible
    })
  }

};

module.exports = FluxCartActions;
```

Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "flux-pricing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Pricing component with flux",
  "main": "app/assets/javascripts/cart.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^0.12.0",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "~>6.3.0",
    "envify": "~3.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.12.2",
    "reactify": "^1.0",
    "watchify": "~2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o app/assets/javascripts/app.js -v -d .",
    "build": "browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > app/assets/javascripts/app.min.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "app/assets/javascripts",
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/__tests__/preprocessor.js",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["react"],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "preprocessor.js",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "reactify",
      "envify"
    ]
  }
}
```

I run tests by running `npm test` in the app directory.

Comment: "When I log out FluxProduct it seems that it is not being automocked"

You mean "FluxCartActions" right ?

Comment: Thanks ncuillery, updated question :)

Comment: Can you add your jest config please ?

Comment: I added my package.json file that has the jest configuration options in them.

Comment: great question (+1) - don't forget to accept an answer if one solved your problem (green checkmark next to the answer)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue could be that you are requiring the mocks in `beforeEach`, which could be un-doing the auto-`genMockFunction` that `jest` does for you.  I just changed some tests I had written to require the modules in the `beforeEach` the same way, and they broke as well, as if the functions weren't mocks.

Try just requiring the dependencies once outside the tests.

```
var React = require('react/addons')
    , TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils
    , FluxProduct = require('../FluxProduct')
    , FluxCartActions = require('../../actions/FluxCartActions');

describe(...);
```

Presumably, you are doing this to "reset" the mocks so that tests don't have side-effects, but I'd be surprised if `jest` doesn't already handle that for you.

Comment: It seems you also have to require the module you are testing only once too - thanks for the pointer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had the same problem not so long ago. Whenever I trigger something from an event the automatic mocking of Jest doesn't seem to work. Maybe it is worth to open an issue on Github.

In the mean time I solved the problem by manual mocking the action at the top of the page:

```
jest.mock('../../actions/FluxCartActions');
```

Not a very elegant solution within Jest but it works. Also I think that you meant this:

```
var addToCartBtn = getElementByTag(product, 'button');
```

instead of

```
var addToCartBtn = getElementByTag(product, 'select');
```

So you can simulate the click of the button and call addToCart.