# Jest : testing simple class with Store dependency

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I having a hard time understanding why my mocked method isnt returning the value I specified with mockReturnValue.  I am testing a simple method that checks a helper on a store to see if a user is authenticated before proceeding. See `connectIfAuth` below.

```
'use strict';

var AuthStore = require('../stores/AuthStore');

console.log('top ' + AuthStore.isAuthenticated());

var TestClass = {
  connect() {
    //...use a mock
  },
  connectIfAuth() {
    console.log('in connect if: ' + AuthStore.isAuthenticated());
    if (AuthStore.isAuthenticated()) { 
      this.connect();
    }
  }
};

module.exports = TestClass;
```

In my test, I want to make the mocked method from the store return true/false and test that the connect() method is called/not-called but the method returns `undefined` within the method I am testing.

```
'use strict';

jest.dontMock('../TestClass.js');

var AuthStore = require('../../stores/AuthStore');

describe('TestClass', function() {
  var TestClass;
  var connectMock;

  beforeEach(function() {
    //the store should return true
    AuthStore.isAuthenticated = jest.genMockFunction().mockReturnValue(true);
    //do I have to require this after I mock out the method(s) in AuthStore?
    TestClass = require('../TestClass');
    connectMock = jest.genMockFunction();
    TestClass.connect = connectMock;
  });

  it('should return the mocked value', function(){
    TestClass.connectIfAuth();
    expect(connectMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); //is 0
  });
});
```

My test output is:

- FAIL  src/scripts/api/**tests**/TestClass-tests.js (0.121s)
- top undefined
- in connect if: undefined
- ● TestClass › it should return the mocked value
- Expected: 0 toBe: 1
- at Spec. (/Users/blabla/projects/my-client/src/scripts/api/**tests**/TestClass-tests.js:20:43)
- at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this same problem - I solved this by putting all of my requires statements outside of the `describe`/`it` blocks. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868369/jest-not-auto-mocking-common-js-modules#comment48182717_28868369), but I also ended up `require`-ing the module I was testing at the top of the file. I assume I'll have to closely manage the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` methods to clean up the mocks I use within my tests.